# ASP. NET CORE 3.1 - How to add Haitian Creole on my culture list?

Tags: asp.net-core

```
 services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
         {
               
             var cultures = new List<CultureInfo>
             {
                 new CultureInfo("pt-BR"),
                 new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                 new CultureInfo("es"),
                 new CultureInfo("ht"),  // <--   Haitian Creole              
                 new CultureInfo("tr"),
                 new CultureInfo("ar")
             };
             options.DefaultRequestCulture = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCulture("pt-BR");
             options.SupportedCultures = cultures;
             options.SupportedUICultures = cultures;
         });
```

Hi there. Is there any way to add Haitian Creole to my list of cultures? Since it is not in the list of supported languages? I've looked in several places, read and reread the localization docs. And I didn't find anything. Can someone help me? Because I know that in NET Framework, it is possible through CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder. But in .Net Core 3.1 I haven't seen anything similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried customizing RequestCultureProvider and using the full name to make it work for me:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc()
                .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix);
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddLocalization(opt => { opt.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });
            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                List<CultureInfo> supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                {
                    new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                    new CultureInfo("de-DE"),
                    new CultureInfo("fr-FR"),
                    new CultureInfo("ht-HT")
                };
                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "ht-HT", uiCulture: "ht-HT");
                options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
                options.RequestCultureProviders.Clear();
                options.AddInitialRequestCultureProvider(new MyCustomRequestCultureProvider(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
            });
        }
```

MyCustomRequestCultureProvider:

```
public class MyCustomRequestCultureProvider : RequestCultureProvider
    {
        CultureInfo Culture ;
        public MyCustomRequestCultureProvider(CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            Culture = cultureInfo;
        }
        public override async Task<ProviderCultureResult> DetermineProviderCultureResult(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            await Task.Yield();
            return new ProviderCultureResult(Culture.ToString());
        }
    }
```

This test is based on this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-a-custom-provider).

Comment: Will try with the full name then. The class MyCustomRequestCultureProvider , should I put on my startup? Ou make a class just for him?

Comment: In theory, as long as you can guarantee to call it normally. For code cleanliness and maintainability, I suggest you create a new class.